# Getting the password from the user

Tags: c, cs50

In this code, I am trying to get the user's information and then to justify if the user is the correct user by asking the user to enter his password.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

//defaults
int acc_user = 0;
string password_user = "" ;
string name_user = "";
int initial_user = 0 ; 

//decalration
void menu();
int select_acc();
int other_info();
int pinTry();
```

Here is the starting of the function,`other_info()` is to access the data base to get their information. After that, printing the name of the user and `pinTry()` is to confirm the password to continue further.

```
//start 
int main ()
{
    other_info();
    printf("Hello , %s\n" , name_user);
    pinTry();
};
void menu()
{
    //display
    printf("1. Balance\n2. Cash withdrawal\n3. Cash deposition\n4. Quit\n");
}
int other_info()
{
    //gets all the info of the acc 
    int i ;
    int acc[6] = {12341 ,12342 ,12342 ,12344,12345 };
    string name[5] = {"aabb" , "ccdd" ,"eeff","gghh","iijj"};
    string password[6] = {"a1b2c3" , "a2b2c3" ,"A3b2c3" , "A4b2c3" , "A5b2c3" };
    int initial[6] =  {5000 , 1000 , 25000 , 700 , 100000};
    i = select_acc();
    return acc_user = acc[i] , name_user = name[i] , password_user = password[i] , initial_user = initial[i] ; 
}
int select_acc()
{
    // finding the account and the other information 
    int acc , i ; 
    printf("Account number: ");
    scanf("%d\n" , &acc);
    if (acc == 12341 )
    { 
        i = 0 ;
    }
    else if (acc == 12342)
    {
        i = 1; 
    }
    else if (acc == 12343 )
    {
        i = 2;
    }
    else if (acc == 12344)
    {
        i = 3;
    }
    else if (acc == 12345)
    {
        i = 4;
    }
    return i ;
};
```

This is the part where I am trying to compare the password .

```
int pinTry()
{
    string input,pin = password_user;
    int pinCount=0;
    while(pinCount <3)
    {
        printf("Enter your pin: ");
        scanf("%s",input);
        pinCount++;
        if(input = pin)
        {
            printf("Success\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect pin\n");
        }

    }
    if(pinCount == 3)
    {
        printf("\nToo many incorrect pins, terminating..\n");
        printf("Password is : %s" , password_user);
        return 1;
    }
};
```

In this code the problem starts when it reaches `pinTry()`, I have no idea why, but the error is Segmentation Fault(core dumped). May I know what I did wrong?

Comment: In the pinTry() function , isn't that ```if( input == pin )``` ?

Comment: It still has that Segmentation Fault error , after changing it :(

Comment: Simplify the select_acc() with a loop instead of one if per acc[] entry. Something like : Define acc[] as a global table (e.g. acc_tab[]) and do a : for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(acc_tab)/sizeof(int)); i ++) if (acc_tab[i] == acc) return i;

Comment: sure do thank you for your recommendation , however the problem is at pinTry() , by taking away pinTry() there are no errors .

Comment: You can't compare strings with "=="', use : if (!strcmp(input, pin)). Moreover, input must be a table with allocated space. What is "string" ? A char * ? Try "char input[50];" for example.

Comment: post tagged as `c` , but `c` does not have `string` datatype and we cannot return multiple values as done in `other_info()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string input,pin = password_user;
```

`string` is defined as `char *` in `cs50.h`, meaning you're allocating input as

```
char *input;
```

since this variable is uninitialized, it is pointing to random memory.

When the line

```
scanf("%s",input);
```

is reached, you attempt to put the data that you read into a random memory location, causing a segfault.

The `cs50.h` library provides a `GetString()` function you can use. Replace

```
scanf("%s",input);
```

with

```
input = GetString();
```

Comment: And string comparison must be done with `strcmp()` too.